# How to clear a customer display using TComPort with Delphi 10.2?

Tags: delphi, pos, tcomport

I am using `TComPort` v6.0 from Winsoft to connect to my `COM5` device which is a customer display from **Oxhoo**.(Prolific PL2303 USB-to-Serial Com Port)

I would like to simply display some text on it and then clear the entire display when a button is pressed. I've already searched for a clear command but it doesn't seem to work like that.

For now I can successfully send text to display using `Comport1.WriteString()` but I can't clear the display or get the text displayed.

Also, sending long string of spaces does visually clear the display but the next text that will be displayed will be at a random position. (last text length + added spaces).

According to the manufacturer it should support ESC/POS commands but I can't figure out which and how to use them in my Delphi code.

The display consists of 2 lines of 20 characters.

```
> [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
> [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
```

How can I clear the display and again write text from the first line?

Comment: Is there any protocol for customer display handling? Does sending long string of spaces clear display? Is "customer display" hardware device with known model name?

Comment: @MBo Thank you for your answer. The customer display's manufacturer is Oxhoo from France. And it's shown as Prolific PL2303 USB-to-Serial Comm Port in computer management. 
I also edited my post to give more informations.

Comment: Prolific is USB-COM converter - not important here, but it is worth to add  `Oxhoo` in question.

Comment: ESC/POS commands are old lineprinter codes which have a typewriter like background: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72   With that in mind, you might try to experiment with the  LF (line feed = go to new line but with same position as current line) and CR (carriage return = move to beginning of the line) commands - hence the DOS/Windows CRLF style for Enter to move to the beginnen of a new line ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to simply clear the display we need to send an ESC/POS command wich is :

```
CLR 0C Clear display screen
```

-> 0C in hex converts to 12 in decimal.

So for Delphi it is as simple as that :

```
Comport1.WriteLine(#12);
```

Comment: OK, so your display supports ESC/POS protocol (details might depend on specific device)

Comment: You can also write `Comport1.WriteLine(#$0C);`, so you don't have to convert the hex values to decimal.

Comment: @MBo yes that's correct. I should have searched deeper in this direction right away. And thank you Delphi Coder for the great tip to avoid converting hex values.